# Set width of a custom environment

Tags: environments, width

I'm trying to make a letter template (I don't want to use the existing one) and I am trying to make an environment for the adress at the top. I want it to be a certain width and located to the right part of the page, but aligned left.

I can not figure out how to do it. Creating custom layouts and templates overall in LaTeX has brought me much headache.

I tried to do something like this:

```
\newenvironment{head}
{\leftskip=2cm}
{\leftskip=0cm}
```

But it doesn't work. :/

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/595333 by @JaazielAguirre.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because of many facts. First of all, TeX uses only *one* value for `\leftskip`, precisely what is current at the end of the paragraph. Secondly, your definition hides the value given to `\leftskip`, because every environment forms a group: so when TeX finds the end of the paragraph, it will have already forgotten the setting to `\leftskip`. If you want to typeset a paragraph with a non zero \leftskip you should define

```
\newenvironment{head}
  {\par\setlength{\leftskip}{2cm}\noindent\ignorespaces}
  {\par}
```

The first `\par` ends the previous text; then we set `\leftskip` and then apply `\noindent` (which requires `\ignorespaces` to ignore the end of line after `\begin{head}`).

At the end we issue `\par` to end the paragraph which will be typeset with the stated setting of `\leftskip`. There's no need to reset `\leftskip` to zero, because that's already taken care of by the end of the implicit group formed by the environment.

### Note

It's better to stick to `\setlength`, because `\leftskip` is a glue parameter; there's an example in the TeXbook: try and define

```
\newenvironment{badidea}
  {\par\leftskip=2cm}
  {\par}
```

and write

```
\begin{badidea}
minuscule chances of error
\end{badidea}
```

You'll have a surprise. :)

Answer (score 2):

The minipage is your friend

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
  Address \\
goes here and is\\
appropriately\\
aligned
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

As an environment:

```
\newenvironment{letteraddress}{\hfill\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}}{\end{minipage}}
```

This of course assumes that `\linewidth` is actually defined. You could always just put in an explicit width if you prefer...

Answer (score 1):

Your question was answered already in  [Set width of algorithm environment (preferably document wide)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7484/set-width-of-algorithm-environment-preferably-document-wide). It is simply using `minipage`s.

The final code should look something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{head}%
{
\centering
\begin{flushright}    
\begin{minipage}{5cm}}%
{
\end{minipage}
\end{flushright}}

\begin{document}
\begin{head}
First line and yeah, the head is right aligned.\\
A second line to show the text inside is left aligned.
\end{head}
Well, here comes the rest of the letter.
\end{document}
```