# Change environment's width

Tags: environments, width

I'm writing my homework and I would like to change the environment's dimensions of

```
\documentclass[10pt,spanish]{article}

% INICIO PAQUETES


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage} % para cambiar dimensiones (recomendado en la web)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm} % gracias a este paquete podemos enlistar los teoremas
\usepackage{hyperref} % permite agregar links

\let\UPproof\proof\def\proof{\small\UPproof}

\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{pro}{Proposici\'on}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}{Corolario}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}{Lema}[section]
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definici\'on}[section]

\textwidth 19cm
\topmargin -2cm
\textheight 23cm
\oddsidemargin -1,2cm
\parindent 0em
\parskip 2ex


\title{Un título}
\date{Una fecha}
\begin{pro} This tense is false.
\end{pro}
\begin{proof}
Because yes, yes.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

I want to make it (the "box" where the proof is being written) an x % smaller than the original "box" where the proposition is, but I don't know how to do it so if someone can help me, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Something like `\let\UPproof\proof\def\proof{\small\UPproof}` placed in the preamble should do. It would certainly be easier to answer your question if you provided a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @yo' I said I don't know how to change it so, I don't know what to show you my "minimal working example". (I knew someone else was going to tell me something similar). I'm sorry :(

Comment: What do you mean by "x % smaller". You don't mean the actual font-size, but rather the width that the `proof` environment takes up with respect to the `\textwidth` or text block containing other text, correct

Comment: yo', your code works pretty cool!

@Werner yes I wanted to mean the lengths of the "box" where the proof is being written (it was my misstake, I'm sorry!)

Comment: Have a look at the changepage package :)

Comment: @UnPerrito: For this, the typical suggestion is to use `adjustwidth` from [`changepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage). See [Indenting a whole paragraph](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35933/5764). What package do you use to provide the `proof` environment?

Comment: @UnPerrito Have you opened the link? I think it's pretty well explained there what MWE means. If you showed a code with one theorem and one proof, containing complete gibberish, and said "and I want the text of the proof to be smaller", it would be enough. But now, the problem is that `amsthm`, `svjour`, `ntheorem` and others implement `proof`, but each in a different way.

Comment: @Werner I don't know, I just know that a "proof" code exist and I use it, so I don't know how to answer that question.

The followings are the packages I'm using: amsmath, fancyhdr,  graphicx, mathrsfs, babel, inputenc, color, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm.

Comment: @yo' done already

Comment: @UnPerrito Sorry to disturb you, but this is not a MWE. If I compile the code you provide, I get `! LaTeX Error: Environment prop undefined.` Instead of listing which packages you use, you could simply construct a short working document which starts with `\documentclass`, contains `\usepackage` with the packages, then `\begin{document}`, then the short piece of code you show, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: @yo' It  is now right? hehe

Comment: @UnPerrito Much better! +1

Comment: `\let\UPproof\proof\def\proof{\small\UPproof}` from @yo' answer should not be in the question. It's the answer.

Comment: I know that @Werner edit the question, but I think the title is `Change environment's fontsize` no?

Comment: @touhami No, it was a misstake from me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `proof` environment from [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) inside an `adjustwidth` environment (from [`changepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage)) with suitable margin adjustments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,letltxmacro,changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\LetLtxMacro\oldproof\proof
\let\endoldproof\endproof
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]
  {\begin{adjustwidth}{2em}{2em}
   \oldproof[#1]}
  {\endoldproof
   \end{adjustwidth}}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{proof}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{proof}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

The margin adjustments above are both `2em` inward from the text block margins.

Comment: Just from a typographical point of view, it would look better with some vertical space above and below.

Comment: @yo' can you, please, cite this?

Comment: I have the following error "Too deeply nested"... googling for solve it.

Comment: DONE!! THANK YOU and THANKS to all for the help! I learned a lot of new things!

Comment: @touhami I can't cite any official source. But note that pull quotes, centered titles, displayed equations, lists etc. -- everything that gets a different horizontal alignment -- is in general separated by vertical space.

Comment: @yo' this is a good point.

Comment: Werner, how can I add the option of reduce the font size in the "proof" environmnent? If I add the code "\let\UPproof\proof\def\proof{\small\UPproof}" it makes an error call "too deeply nested" :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need, but with an background color. This post is from 9 years ago but maybe someone could need too.

use **mdframe**, like the next example:

```
newcounter{definicion}[section]
\newenvironment{definicion}[1]
{
\begin{flushright}
\refstepcounter{definicion}\par\medskip \noindent \textbf
{\textit{#1}.} - Definición \thesection.\thedefinicion
\end{flushright}
\begin{center}
\begin{mdframed}[userdefinedwidth=0.75\textwidth, 
align=center, linewidth=0pt, backgroundcolor=lightgray]
\smallskip
}
{
\smallskip
\end{mdframed}
\end{center}
}
```

This is an screenshot from the pdf output:

---

[image]

---

You can defime widht, color background and more. even the centering, not of text but the frame. See the [CTAN page mdframed](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed).