# Set horizontal width on custom listings environment

Tags: listings

I want to create a custom listings environment and want to set its width as something like 90% of textwidth, centred.

Per an [earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7484/set-width-of-algorithm-environment-preferably-document-wide) for algorithms, the first thing I tried was to embed the listing in a minipage environment. However, [custom listing environments must be done through the `\lstnewenvironment` command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78992/listings-environment). I found a way to still make standard environment work, but it requires to use the escape command every time before ending the environment.

The second thing I tried was this latter command, but as far as I can see, it doesn't offer a feature to set the width of the listing or centre it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\lstnewenvironment{queryl} %% APPROACH 1
 {\lstset{frame=shadowbox,escapechar=`}}
 {}

\newenvironment{query} %% APPROACH 2
 {\begin{minipage}{4cm}\centering\begin{queryl}}
 {\end{queryl}\end{minipage}}


\begin{document}
%% APPROACH 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.
\begin{queryl}
begin
{ do nothing }
end ;
\end{queryl}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.

%% APPROACH 2
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.

\begin{query}
begin
{ do nothing }
end ;`%<- needs escape-to-LaTeX character to work
\end{query}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can note that for the first environment, the frame extends beyond the width of the text. Also, puzzlingly the `minipage` environment doesn't seem to want to centre and swallows space (though I guess I could *perhaps* at least get that to work with tinkering).

In any case, does anyone have any ideas on how to set a width for a custom listings environment and centre it without requiring use of the escape character each time to end the environment?

Comment: For your second approach, you can center the whole listings box by `\newenvironment{query} %% APPROACH 2
 {\begin{center}\begin{minipage}{4cm}\centering\begin{queryl}}
 {\end{queryl}\end{minipage}\end{center}}`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can specify the width with `\lstset{linewidth=<length>}`.

To incorporate this into your custom environment:

```
\lstnewenvironment{queryl}
   {\lstset{frame=shadowbox,escapechar=`,linewidth=6cm}}
   {}
```

---

However, I would actually suggest you define the `queryl` environment to be able to accept an optional first parameter in case you need to adjust any parameters locally:

```
\lstnewenvironment{queryl}[1][] 
   {\lstset{frame=shadowbox,escapechar=`,linewidth=8cm, #1}}
   {}
```

Now when you use this as

```
\begin{queryl}
 ...
\end{queryl}
```

you get the first image below, but with

```
\begin{queryl}[linewidth=10cm]
 ...
\end{queryl}
```

you would obtain the second version:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{queryl}[1][] 
 {\lstset{frame=shadowbox,escapechar=`,linewidth=8cm, #1}}
 {}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.
\begin{queryl}
begin
{ listing with default line width }
end ;
\end{queryl}

\begin{queryl}[linewidth=10cm]
begin
{ listing with width adjust locally }
end ;
\end{queryl}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Completely missed that in the documentation. (Section 4.10 for posterity)  
  
http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf 
  
Thanks!